# add a button as a Left/Right window command

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

i'm working in WPF project i'm using [ModernUI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)
[image: modernui]

in there sample they made the HELP and Settings i need to know how. i want to set the logout button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of Modern UI Navigation App is in a way that making your `logout` link work like a button is not simply possible.

What you can do is to look for tag below in MainWindow.xaml :

```
<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

then add this tag as its last child:

```
    <mui:Link DisplayName="logout" Source="/Pages/LogoutPage.xaml"></mui:Link>
```

With this you need to create a new page in Pages folder called LogoutPage and put the code required to execute for Logout in it's Constructor method and if you want navigate back.